# How to have differents routes for each languages

Tags: playframework, routes, playframework-1.x, lang

I'm working with Play Framework 1.2.4, and i wanted to know if there is way to have differents routes for each languages, which point to the same controller/action (specially for the SEO).

For example, i want :

```
GET /en/how-it-works           myController.howItWorks
GET /fr/comment-ca-marche      myController.howItWorks
```

The problem is that the reverse routing start on the top of the route file, so if i'm on the  `/fr` part of the website, the links `@{myController.howItWorks}` will result in `/en/how-it-works`

To complete my case, i'm using a parameter `lang` as a routeArgs, and here's my route file :

```
GET /{lang}/how-it-works        myController.howItWorks
```

`myController` have a `@Before` method that set the `lang` routeArgs. This code is working, i got `/en/how-it-works` and if i change the language to fr i got `/fr/how-it-works`

I've tried this in my route file, but it doesn't work

```
%{if (lang == 'fr') {   }%
GET /{lang}/comment-ca-marche  myController.howItWorks
%{ } else { }%
GET /{lang}/how-it-work        myController.howItWorks
%{ } }%
```

The `lang` parameter seems to be `null`, so i can't dynamically choose the right route.
I would like to know if someone has got the same problem,

Thank you for your help

(and sorry for my english...)

Answer (score 0):

It should work.

I have the following routes

```
GET     /{lang}/users/list                      Application.generateLink
```

and relevant controller method

```
public static void index(String lang) { ... }
```

in my view

```
<li class=""><a href="@{UserManager.index(lang)}">&{'navigation.users.view'}</a></li>
```

in somewhat simplistic changeLanguage code. You simply set the language if it is null.

```
public static void changeLanguage(String lang) {
    if (lang != null) {
        String property = Play.configuration.getProperty("application.langs");
        if (property.contains(lang)) {
            Lang.change(lang);
        }
    } else {
        lang = "en";
        Lang.change(lang);
    }
    String replacement = String.format("/%s/", lang);
    if (lang.equals("en")) {
        redirect(request.headers.get("referer").value().replace("/fr/", replacement));
    } else {
        redirect(request.headers.get("referer").value().replace("/en/", replacement));
    }
}
```

it works on URLs when you change language.

you could create a custom java tag to generate the links. The input will be `id`, `text`, and generate a link with the correct attributes. Have a look at http://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.5/templates (section Custom Java Tags)

hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but i've already made this part of the code (i set the lang in the routeArgs and i get it in my route files). My problem is that i want a route by lang : `{lang}/how-it-works` and `{lang}/comment-ca-marche` pointing to the same controller/action. For the moment i just have `fr/how-it-works` and `en/how-it-works`.

Comment: ah, you need to insert some sort of id or constant i.e could be {lang}/{id}/{text} - based on the ID, you can replace the text, but ID needs to remain constant. Barring this solution, you will need to maintain a mapping yourself, which translates (how-it-works <==> commen-ca-marche back and forth). This is more involved, but should be doable. Important note would be that, you will have a generic controller and the text would change based on the language. I doubt if you can have multiple static routes. Perhaps, someone else can shed some light on it.

Comment: have a look at Custom Java docs in the updated link. I think it will provide the intermediate layer where you can generate the correct code.